# Determine $\left \{ u\geq a \right \}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, and is $u$ $\mathcal B(\mathbb{R})/\mathcal B(\mathbb{R})$-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, measurable-functions, borel-sets

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $u(x)=\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$. Determine the set $\left \{ u\geq a \right \}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $u$ is $\mathcal B(\mathbb{R})/\mathcal B(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.

Note that the notation of the set can be understood as
$$\left \{ u\geq a \right \}=\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}:u(x)\geq a \right \} =u^{-1}([a,\infty)).$$

I am unable to answer the other problem without the determined set. Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

to show it's measurable, you just have to take the inverse image of a generating set of the range and show that's a measurable set in the domain.  So,  [a,b],  for real numbers a and b  generate the borel sets (Closed intervals.  Open intervals work as well).   The pre-image of u of this set is going to be all the x values who's floor is between a and b.  This you can show is an interval itself, by looking at a few simple cases.

If you still don't have it by tomorrow,  I can edit this to finish the details.

Comment: I've been trying to think about it for hours and I still am unable to get started the correct way. It's probably because of my incorrect understanding of the question about determining the set. All I could do is just saying that $\{u\geq a\} = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : \left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor \geq a\}= \{x\in \mathbb{R} : x \geq \left \lceil{a}\right \rceil \}$.

Comment: I still don't have it now.