# Find $\{u \geq a\}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $u(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$

Tags: measure-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, measurable-functions, borel-sets

Let $u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $u(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$.

(i) Determine $\{u \geq a\}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

(ii) Show that $u$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) / \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measureable.

---

(i) I'm not sure what the notation mean. I guess it is $\{u: u \ge a,\forall a\in\mathbb{R}\}$. But this will just be all the integers by the definition of $u$. (**?**)

(ii) I can probably do this one myself.

Comment: $\{u\geq a\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | u(x) \geq a\}$.

Comment: or if you prefer $u^{-1}\left( [a,+\infty) \right)$

Comment: @alphaomega I think $a$ is included.

Comment: @Xenusi I have included it

Comment: @user295959 I can't actually figure it out. So I should find all $x$ s. t. the function value of $x$ is bigger than some $a$. So the function value is an integer. and for a to bigger that an integer. Could a get  a HINT?

Comment: An exact duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955061/determine-left-u-geq-a-right-for-all-a-in-mathbbr-and-is-u-m?rq=1)

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry. But I simply do not understand how  one can find a duplicate.

Comment: In this case I just saw that on the right hand side, under "Related". In general, you may try [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), which is extreme good in searching the site.

Comment: Another very similar one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941080/show-that-a-function-is-a-borel-function)

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks!

Comment: @Xenusi, can you solve the problem for some concrete $a$? For example, what is $\{u\geq 2.7\}$?

Comment: please note that $\{u \ge a\} = \{x\mid u(x) \ge a\} \ne  \{x\mid u(x) \ge a, \forall a \in \Bbb R\}$. In the latter set, $a$ is a dummy variable, and the set is empty as it requires $u(x)$ to be infinitely large. In the former set, $a$ is a parameter, defined separately from the set notation, and you get a different set for each value of $a$. Since the "$\forall a \in \Bbb R$" is *outside* the set notation in the problem, your task is to find an expression defining each of the sets without referencing $u$.

Comment: @Ennar $\{u\ge 2.7\}$ is $\{ x: x \ge 3 \}$, right?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I thought it was the same. Also, you say that $u(x)$ has to be infinity large. But it is not a problem since it can be infinitely large, just choose $x$ big enough.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So $x \ge \left \lceil{a}\right \rceil $, right? 
Then I think I understand.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think it is right to write $\{u: u \geq a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ instead of $\{u: u \geq a, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ ?

Comment: (1) In the set $\{x\mid \forall a \in \Bbb R, u(x) \ge a\}$, (the order of the $\forall$ clause and the condition does not matter in this case) any particular real number $x$ will be in the set if $u(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ is $\ge$ *every* real number $a$. Because $x + 1$ is a real number, this requires that $\lfloor x \rfloor \ge x + 1$, which is never true. There is no $x$ that is "big enough". (2) yes, for any real number $a, \{u \ge a\} = \{x\mid x \ge \lceil a \rceil\}$. (3) I disagree. While people will eventually decide the 1st must mean the 2nd, it is much better to  just use the 2nd.